# 'for a in x:' not working over 'for x in x:'

Tags: python

I am writing a program that sorts an input of names into a alphabetical list.
The output should be:

> Students: Peng Ivan Alan Jodi Macy

Class Roll

> Alan
>
> Ivan
>
> Jodi
>
> Macy
>
> Peng

I have the code working, but when I'm printing the names on seperate lines, if I write:

```
for a in names:
  print(names)
```

It prints it all on one line, but if I write:

```
for names in names:
   print(names)
```

It works fine. 
(Names is the list of names). 
Why is this?

Comment: thats because you are using same variable name i.e. `names`

Comment: In any case I think you mean: `for a in names:  print(a)`

Comment: `for a in names:..print(names)` Eventhough you are iterating through the `names`, you are still printing the full `names` in each iteration

Comment: For your first example you tried to print whatever assigned to `names` for the number of time `names` was iterated, rather, you should `print(a)`, as `a` is where each element is assigned by the for loop.

Comment: for a in names:print (a),

Comment: I AM SO STUPID, I CAN'T BELIEVE I DIDN'T REALISE THIS

Comment: This is happening because you are using same variable `name` for printing.. Try: `for a in names: print(a)`

Comment: @jack.py, you may accept an answer by clicking on the tick mark beside it, if it helped. Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
names = ['Alan','Ivan','Jodi','Macy','Peng']

# This will print whatever is assigned to `names` for the number of times `names` is iterated
for a in names:
  print(names)
```

OUTPUT:

```
['Alan', 'Ivan', 'Jodi', 'Macy', 'Peng']
['Alan', 'Ivan', 'Jodi', 'Macy', 'Peng']
['Alan', 'Ivan', 'Jodi', 'Macy', 'Peng']
['Alan', 'Ivan', 'Jodi', 'Macy', 'Peng']
['Alan', 'Ivan', 'Jodi', 'Macy', 'Peng']
```

Now:

```
# You're using same variable name for printing
for names in names:
   print(names)
```

> Extra Note: As @buran stated: This is valid, but not desirable to use,
>   because at the end value of `names` will be the last element in the
>   list, not the original list `names`

OUTPUT:

```
Alan
Ivan
Jodi
Macy
Peng
```

Finally:

```
# This is what you need i.e. for each name in names, print the name
for name in names
   print(name)
```

OUTPUT:

```
Alan
Ivan
Jodi
Macy
Peng
```

Comment: maybe add the note that using `for names in names` is valid, but not desirable to use, because at the end value of `names` will be the last element in the list, not the original list `names`

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you are using same varible `name` for printing.

Try :

```
for a in names:
   print(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

In for loop you are storing each iteration value in variable a while in print statement you are referencing the names variable which is holding all values. That's why it is printing all values at same line:

change your code

```
for a in names:
  print(names)
```

with

```
for a in names:
  print(a)
```